# Selecting text programmatically in menu view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I write an "Agent" Cocoa app where I have TextField in status icon's menu, it looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ifotos.pl](http://s3.ifotos.pl/img/Zrzut-ekr_hwaqnwa.png))</sub>

And in couple of places I select its contents programmatically (e.g. in -(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder of my NSTextField subclass)

And it doesn't work. It surely has something to do with the fact that it's in menu, not in window. But how do I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘select its contents’, and what’s the code you’re using to do that?

Comment: I mean NSTextField's selectText:

Comment: Have you configured the text field to be selectable?

Comment: Are you able to select it normally, e.g by dragging the mouse?

Comment: I've just written a little sample project of my own and it seems to work fine as can be seen here: http://cl.ly/996z

Comment: Sure, I can select it manually. Also, for some reason, selection made in IB action (invoked, e.g. by clicking a button) works, but in any other place doesn't. I tried invoking it using GCD etc., but I just can't make it work. Also, I came across other problems with NSMenu, so I guess I have no other choice but to implement NSWindow subclass imitating NSMenu.

Comment: apparently NSMenu wasn't made for this kind of stuff ;(

Comment: Hmm. So which specific places does calling `selectText:` not work?

Comment: immediately after popping up NSStatusItem's menu as well as in my NSTextField sublass's - (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder

Comment: When you say 'after popping up NSStatusItem's menu' is that in the NSMenu's 'menuWillOpen:' delegate method?

Comment: No. it's [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:menu];

Comment: Ah, you're right it doesn't work for me either. From what I can tell, I guess it doesn't work simply because the menu hasn't appeared yet. If you become the `menu`'s delegate and in the `menuWillOpen:` method do what Rob Keniger suggests it seems to work (at least for me anyway :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a window instead? Menus are implemented as windows under the hood: you can do the same thing, just position and style your window appropriately.

Edit: answer largely rewritten

Comment: What? No... I just want to select text in text field programatically... No need for contextual menus, just text field contents selected.

Comment: Also, the Spotlight menu doe display a contextual menu if you right-click the search box. I'll change my suggestion.

Comment: I don't think I speak Cocoa well enough to do this nicely. But I came across another problem with NSTextField in menu (sometimes it just becames not selectable), so probably I will have to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Because your view is in a menu, it's possible that the textfield isn't responding because the run loop is not in its default mode. Try calling `selectText:` like this:

```
[textField performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:nil 
afterDelay:0.0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

Comment: no, it doesn't (or it seems so): if I create regular NSTextField and my subclass RPTextField in a window, and click on text in them, in my implementation text is selected, in NSTextField only cursor is placed. So my implementation is fine, and it's about the menu. If I just call [textField selectText:self] somewhere, it doesn't work either.

Comment: You're pretty much correct. I've changed my answer to one that might help you better.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I'm afraid it still doesn't work as expected :(

Comment: This actually seems to fix the problem in my test app when it is called from `menuWillOpen:`. Are you sure it doesn't work @radex?

Comment: Yes! It works! Unfortunately I will have to write my own menu implementation (and it's mostly done), so I won't use that. But thanks!